# How to get stuck in a for loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, while-loop, wait

I have a problem where I need to wait in a for loop for a while till the value of a Boolean variable is changed. I intentionally want to wait in the loop. Sample code:

```
check = True  

def change_check_value():
    global check
    ###
    after a while check changes to true
    ###

change_check_vale()  #running on a different thread

for i in range(0,10):
    print(i)
    check = False
    ## wait till check becomes true and continue the for loop
```

I want to wait in the for loop till the check becomes true again. I tried with while loop but I was not able to achieve the functionality. `time.sleep()` cannot be used because I am not sure of how much time to wait.

Comment: You can use `time.sleep`, you just might end up waiting longer than you really need to.  The other option is a [condition variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the method as mentioned in this post : [Is there an easy way in Python to wait until certain condition is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785821/is-there-an-easy-way-in-python-to-wait-until-certain-condition-is-true)

```
import time

check = True

def wait_until():
  while true:
    if check == True: return


def change_check_value():
    global check
    ###
    after a while check changes to true
    ###

change_check_vale()  #running on a different thread

for i in range(0,10):
    print(i)
    check = False
    ## wait till check becomes true and continue the for loop
    wait_until()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24885230)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the review.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Event* object, it may be found under *threading* and under the *asyncio* packages.

The event object have a *wait()* method and while calling it the code will not continue until the Event will set to true.
Once the event will be set to *True* the code will immediately continue.

asyncio example ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event)):

```
async def waiter(event):
    print('waiting for it ...')
    await event.wait()
    print('... got it!')

async def main():
    # Create an Event object.
    event = asyncio.Event()

    # Spawn a Task to wait until 'event' is set.
    waiter_task = asyncio.create_task(waiter(event))

    # Sleep for 1 second and set the event.
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    event.set()

    # Wait until the waiter task is finished.
    await waiter_task

asyncio.run(main())
```

Threading example ([source](http://import%20threading%20import%20time%20import%20logging%20%20logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format='(%25(threadName)-9s)%20%25(message)s',)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20wait_for_event(e):%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('wait_for_event%20starting')%20%20%20%20%20event_is_set%20=%20e.wait()%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('event%20set:%20%25s',%20event_is_set)%20%20def%20wait_for_event_timeout(e,%20t):%20%20%20%20%20while%20not%20e.isSet():%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('wait_for_event_timeout%20starting')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event_is_set%20=%20e.wait(t)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('event%20set:%20%25s',%20event_is_set)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20event_is_set:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('processing%20event')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('doing%20other%20things')%20%20if%20__name__%20==%20'__main__':%20%20%20%20%20e%20=%20threading.Event()%20%20%20%20%20t1%20=%20threading.Thread(name='blocking',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target=wait_for_event,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20args=(e,))%20%20%20%20%20t1.start()%20%20%20%20%20%20t2%20=%20threading.Thread(name='non-blocking',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target=wait_for_event_timeout,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20args=(e,%202))%20%20%20%20%20t2.start()%20%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('Waiting%20before%20calling%20Event.set()')%20%20%20%20%20time.sleep(3)%20%20%20%20%20e.set()%20%20%20%20%20logging.debug('Event%20is%20set'))):

```
import threading
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)

def wait_for_event(e):
    logging.debug('wait_for_event starting')
    event_is_set = e.wait()
    logging.debug('event set: %s', event_is_set)

def wait_for_event_timeout(e, t):
    while not e.isSet():
        logging.debug('wait_for_event_timeout starting')
        event_is_set = e.wait(t)
        logging.debug('event set: %s', event_is_set)
        if event_is_set:
            logging.debug('processing event')
        else:
            logging.debug('doing other things')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = threading.Event()
    t1 = threading.Thread(name='blocking', 
                      target=wait_for_event,
                      args=(e,))
    t1.start()

    t2 = threading.Thread(name='non-blocking', 
                      target=wait_for_event_timeout, 
                      args=(e, 2))
    t2.start()

    logging.debug('Waiting before calling Event.set()')
    time.sleep(3)
    e.set()
    logging.debug('Event is set')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a very straightforward way:

```
from threading import Event, Thread

event = Event()


def wait_for_it(e):
    print('Waiting for something to happen.')
    e.wait()
    print('No longer waiting.')
    e.clear()
    print('It can happen again.')


def make_it_happen(e):
    print('Making it happen.')
    e.set()
    print('It happened.')


# create the threads
threads = [Thread(target=wait_for_it, args=(event,)), Thread(target=make_it_happen, args=(event,))]

# start them
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

# make the main thread wait for the others to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```